# Meaning of fourth-power-free integer?

Tags: number-theory

In a paper on Elliptic curves, there is the term, 'fourth-power-free integer', what does it mean? Is it something like square free integer?

Comment: Not divisible by the fourth power of an integer (except $\pm 1$).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, yeah, just the equivalent of it for fourth powers - a "fourth power free" integer's prime factors repeat no more than three times.